Mean-variance optimisation with and without constraints
I wrote the following code for a portfolio project but I have an issue.

The first function calculates the mean-variance optimisation based on the lambda (risk propensity), the vector of expected returns mu and the covariance matrix. The only constraint here is a budget constraint so that the sum of weights = 1
The second function maximises the target function (in this case minimises the negative of the target function) where lambda represents a risk propensity factor. I can set the bounds to (0,1) to specify no shorts.

However if I specify bounds (None, None), I would expect to get the same results as the mvo function, but I do not. Results are completely different. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!!
*Edit: added imports
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# mean-variance optimisation no constraints
def mvo(lambda_risk, mu, cov_m):
    w = (1/(2*lambda_risk)) * inv(cov_m) @ mu
    return w
       
# Objective function used for optimisation under "no-shorts" constraint (see below)
def portfolio_objective(w, lambda_risk, mu, cov_m):
    return w.T @ cov_m @ w - lambda_risk * mu.T @ w
    
# Mean-variance optimisation with constraint = no short positions (non negative weights only)
def mvo_no_short(lambda_risk, mu, cov_m):
    
    n_assets = len(mu)
    
    # Constraints: Sum of weights equals 1
    constraints = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda w: np.sum(w) - 1}
    
    # Bounds: No short selling (weights >= 0)
    bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(n_assets)]
    
    # Initial guess (e.g., equal weights)
    initial_weights = np.ones(n_assets) / n_assets
    
    # Solve the optimization problem
    result = minimize(
        portfolio_objective, 
        initial_weights, 
        args=(lambda_risk, mu, cov_m),  
        bounds=bounds, 
        constraints=constraints
    )
  
    return result.x


In case someone wants to run this code, can you please show any import statements that are needed at the beginning.

You are right, sorry. I added them now. Thanks.

A key subtlety lies in the fact that your first function,
$$ \texttt{mvo}(\lambda_{\text{risk}}, \mu, \Sigma) \;=\; \frac{1}{2\,\lambda_{\text{risk}}}\,\Sigma^{-1}\,\mu, $$
does not enforce $\sum_i w_i = 1$, while your second function does. Even if you replace the bounds with $(-\infty, \infty)$, the second function still imposes the budget constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$. Hence, you should not expect the solver-based approach with constraints={'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda w: sum(w) - 1} and bounds=[(None, None), ..., (None, None)] to return the same weights as the closed-form unconstrained solution. To see why, consider the following objective that your solver is minimizing:
$$ \min_{w}\;\; w^\mathsf{T}\,\Sigma\,w \;-\; \lambda_{\text{risk}}\,\mu^\mathsf{T}\,w \quad \text{subject to} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \;=\;1 \quad \text{and possibly } w_i \ge 0 \text{ if no-shorts.} $$
Let us derive the closed-form solution with (only) the budget constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$. Form a Lagrangian:
$$ \mathcal{L}(w, \alpha) \;=\; w^\mathsf{T} \Sigma \,w \;-\; \lambda_{\text{risk}}\, \mu^\mathsf{T} w \;+\; \alpha\, \Bigl(\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n w_i - 1\Bigr), $$
where $\alpha$ is the Lagrange multiplier enforcing $\sum_i w_i = 1$. Taking the gradient with respect to $w$ and setting it to zero gives
$$ 2\,\Sigma\,w \;-\; \lambda_{\text{risk}}\,\mu \;+\; \alpha \,\mathbf{1} \;=\; 0, $$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones. Meanwhile, the constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$ still applies. If you solve these simultaneously, you get something of the form
$$ w^* \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\,\Sigma^{-1}\,\bigl(\lambda_{\text{risk}}\mu - \alpha^* \mathbf{1}\bigr), \quad \text{and} \quad \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n w^i = 1, $$
so there is an additional "$\alpha\mathbf{1}$" term that adjusts the weights so that they sum to 1. In contrast, the unconstrained optimum from your first function,
$$ w_{\text{unconstrained}}^* \;=\; \frac{1}{2\,\lambda_{\text{risk}}} \,\Sigma^{-1}\,\mu, $$
omits that $\alpha\,\mathbf{1}$ term precisely because you did not require $\sum_i w_i=1$. Numerically, the unconstrained solution will generally not satisfy the budget constraint once you sum its entries. Therefore, even with bounds $(-\infty, \infty)$, you are solving two different problems.
Put another way, if you truly want the solver-based approach to reproduce the same exact weights as $\frac{1}{2\,\lambda_{\text{risk}}}\,\Sigma^{-1}\,\mu$, you must remove the budget constraint altogether. In pseudocode form (schematically),
constraints = ()  # or constraints = None
bounds = [(None, None) for _ in range(n_assets)]
initial_guess = np.zeros(n_assets)  # or any guess
result = minimize(
    portfolio_objective,
    initial_guess,
    args=(lambda_risk, mu, cov_m),
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=constraints
)

Under these conditions (no sum-of-weights constraint, no non-negativity constraint), the solver's answer should match the closed-form $\frac{1}{2\,\lambda_{\text{risk}}}\Sigma^{-1}\mu$. But once you add $\sum_i w_i = 1$ or $w_i \geq 0$, you are in a different optimization problem, and the result will (and should) deviate from the unconstrained closed-form solution.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Thank you so much for your kind reply and explanation. Indeed bad oversight from my side.
I tried to do things step by step adding a budget constraint to the mean-variance optimisation formula.
$\mathcal{L} = \mathbf{w}^T \Sigma \mathbf{w} - \lambda \mathbf{w}^T \mu + \gamma \left( \mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{w} - 1 \right)$
$\dfrac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{w}}= 2\Sigma\mathbf{w}\ -\lambda \mathbf{\mu} - \gamma\mathbf{1^T}         $
$\dfrac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{\gamma}}= 1- \mathbf{1}\mathbf{w}
$
from which I get:
$\gamma = \dfrac{\mathbf{1^T}\Sigma^{-1}\lambda\mathbf{\mu}-1}{\mathbf{1^T}\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$
and replacing this into the equation above I get the optimal w weights enforcing the budget constraint that the sum of all weights must be one.
Implementing it in Python:
def new_mvo_budget_constraint(lambda_risk, mu, cov_m):
    ones = np.ones(len(cov_m))
    gamma = (lambda_risk * ones.T @ inv(cov_m) @ mu - 1) / multi_dot([ones.T, inv(cov_m), ones])
    w = (lambda_risk * mu - gamma * ones.T)@ inv(cov_m)
    
    return w

Unfortunately even now, I get substantially different results than the other optimisation function using scipy. Cleary I am making a mistake in the calculations, but I spent a day looking for the error and can't find it. Also tried chatgpt, but his answers are all over the place. Anyone can spot an obvious error in my derivatives?
